# axios post api data sent gives empty object on console.log(req.body) on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have started with nodejs and have been trying to send data in the post api using axios but not getting it in the server side here is my setup

CLIENT

```
export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'JWT fefege...'
    }
    let data = { title: "abc", price: 20 }; // i am sending this data 
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/add-product", data, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
 
  render() {
    return (<div></div>);
  }
}
```

SERVERS SIDE

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
let cors = require("cors");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/product");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(productRoutes);
app.listen(5000)
```

products routes.js file

```
const express = require('express');

const productController = require('../controllers/product');

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/add-product', productController.addProduct);
module.exports=router
```

controller file

```
 exports.addProduct = (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body) //gives me {} everytime
 }
```

here eveytime i send an object from client side i see {} as console

Both my projects runs on localhost:3000 and 5000 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```